# How to apply terraform.tfvars in azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines, terraform-provider-azure

Trying to use azure devops pipeline to build AKS using terraform, i wish i can pass variable values from prod_terraform.tfvars file
i want to run "terraform plan -var-file = prod_terraform.tfvars"

Here, is the yaml code

```
      - task: TerraformCLI@0
        displayName: Terraform Plan
        inputs:
          command: 'plan'
          workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/terraform-manifests'
          commandOptions: '-out aks_cluster.tfplan'
          allowTelemetryCollection: false
```

below is the error

```
/opt/hostedtoolcache/terraform/1.0.8/x64/terraform plan -out aks_cluster.tfplan
Acquiring state lock. This may take a few moments...
var.acr_demo
  Enter a value: 
##[error]The operation was canceled.
Finishing: Terraform Plan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terraform will automatically load the variable values from the variable definition file if it is named terraform.tfvars or ends in .auto.tvfars and placed in the same directory as the other configuration files like below:

```
development
└── server
    └── main.tf
    └── variables.tf
    └── terraform.tfvars
```

I renamed the file and it worked